# Using a .htaccess file to set specific expire rules for different folders

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have 5 symlinked folders on my website that are pulling data folders that are located in the home folder of my hosting.

`/home/public_html/myfolder` symlink points to `/home/folder1/` **the pages are generated on the fly by python.**

My public_html has a .htaccess file that has numerous rules setup for expiring file types for the whole of public_html...

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    # RSS feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
</IfModule>
```

I'm wanting to setup specific rules for `/home/public_html/myfolder`, someone mentioned using `<DirectoryMatch>` or/and `<FilesMatch>` but I can't seem to get anything to work using it.

For example, by default the RSS/XML should have an access time of 1 hour and the `/myfolder/` should have an access time of 10 seconds.

How would I make it do that with the `.htaccess` file that is located in `/home/public_html`

Comment: I was wondering if my answer was able to address your question.  If so, I'd appreciate an upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted so I can receive credit.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<DirectoryMatch>` directive is only valid in a conf file, but if you don't have access to modify that, a natural way to solve this would be to put an .htaccess file with the other expiration rules in /home/folder1 where they'd then override the site-wide rules.